# How can I add a fuse/breaker to an extension cable?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a [Bayco 800 cord reel](https://www.baycoproducts.com/productsbayco/retractable-reels/item/sl-800)  that (*insanely!*) has a non-replaceable 10A fuse in the outlet that I blew.

I was going to replace the end with something like [this](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/3w102-e): , but then I'll have a 16awg wire (*in the reel*) on a 15A breaker.

Is there any way to add a 10A breaker-like-device to a 3-prong outlet so just this reel will be protected from > 10A?

If not a breaker, is there at least a way to add a replaceable fuse to a 3-prong cable?

Comment: Non-replaceable? That seems strange. On the one hand, that means one accidental overcurrent situation - which could *easily* happen with a 3-outlet cord - you might be diligent about making sure each device is < 10A (no heaters) but mess up on 3 devices at one time - and you've ruined it, so the manufacturer can save $0.50 by using a hardwired fuse instead of a fuse holder. On the other hand, that saves them from liability of "10A fuse blew, stick in a 20A fuse" followed by burning up the cord with 20A load (but never tripping the circuit breaker because it is plugged into a 20A circuit).

Comment: Are you sure there's not a reset button somewhere on the outlet strip?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes, totally strange, but all of the bad reviews on the product on Amazon say that's the case :(. That is exactly what I did - I had no idea it was only 10A so I plugged in a heat gun and poof...

Comment: @JACK Yes, I contacted Bayco and there is no reset button - if you blow it you blow it. Totally ridiculous... but seems like it should be fixable but I can't seem to find a device like I described in the question.

Comment: What's crazy is that such a nice cord/reel would be so thin. 10A is right for 16 AWG, but for $1.00 they could bump it up to at least 15A/14 AWG - which would be sufficient because while you might plug it into a 20A circuit, the socket configuration would limit you to 15A appliances. But the problem is again that the manufacturers want to shave every penny to get to a low price-point to get to the impulse buyers, etc. But I digress...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The manual says nothing about a fuse. But the web page says "10amp rating", and they enforce it with a fuse. I have to wonder if ETL required that on the basis that the design (reel designed to be permanently mounted, clearly designed for outdoor == **plug lots of tools into it** use, etc.). On the other hand, for an extra $4 they could have thrown a hair-dryer style embedded GFCI, which for people using this on an older non-GFCI receptacle would provide life-safety when using this with tools outside in the rain/snow & likely more important than overcurrent protection.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Three reasons: 1) I plugged in something that probably drew more than 10A and the reel stopped working. 2) The reviews on Amazon all complain about this "fuse" (that I agree isn't listed anywhere by Bayco) 3) I emailed Bayco and they told me if I drew more than 10A I'm just out of luck.

Comment: I also wonder if the problem (ending in a requirement of fused protection) is that while 15A on a 16 AWG extension cord is not in & of itself the end of the world, if 25' of that cord is rolled up on an enclosed reel at the time (e.g., plugged in heater in garage right next to the reel vs. cord extended for outside use) then the overcurrent issue with respect to wire heating may be a real-world concern.

Comment: I believe they do that to protect the sliding contacts, possibly a UL thing to get a listing in the US when designed for the UK 250v that has lower current requirements. I am sure it could be hacked but probably not easy by design. Give it 1 star rating if you find it online. If you are sure the fuse is in the end replace the thing. How to tell plug in and use a non contact voltage indicator if there is no voltage at the wires replacing the cord cap with one that could be fused could be an option, if the voltage is there all the way to the female replace that. I would try but I do this daily.

Comment: @DavidDoria OK I'm a believer.  Sounds like ETL made them fit a fuse or fusible link as a condition of certification.

Answer (score 3):

### Fatal flaw: You can't use extension cords coiled up!

This entire product's *very design* is faulty.   Obviously the design intent is that you furl out just as much cord as you *need*, and then leave the rest neatly on the spool.  But you run smack into NEC 310.15(B)(3)(a):

[image]

A spool counts as a raceway.  That spool could potentially hold 11-20 wraps of wire.  Hot and neutral count but ground does not, so that's 22-40 wires.  The table calls for a 40% derate - very extreme.  Normally, wire ampacity is limited by several other derates, fortunately this does not stack with them, it derates off the "theoretical perfectly cooled" ampacity.  At 90 degrees C, that is 18 amps for #16. **40% of 18A is 7.2 amps.**

(and we're being generous here; if we hold #16 to 60C temp, your limit is more like 4A).

And when you violate that, you get this.

[image]

As you can see, *this product is a total loser from the day it was drawn on the back of a napkin in a bar*.

And that's where the CE rating came from.  These epsilon-minuses had lined up the factory and faked their CE rating *before they even realized you need a UL listing (or other third-party Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory) to sell in the United States*.
UL told them to take a hike.
CSA told them to take a hike.
ETL (by golly, when there's a marginal product in need of approval it always seems to be ETL), approved the product *on condition of adding a fuse*.  So they had two choices: be yet another Chinese seller shoveling junk onto wish.com, DealExtreme, Amazon and eBay... OR, be in Home Depot.  So they bit their lip and said "alright, fuse it is".

*Hey, the NRTLs certify safety, not product quality or fitness of purpose*.

### Then you decide you want to modify it.

Statutorially, this is modifying equipment contrary to instructions, and is a violation of NEC 110.2 and 110.3(B).

You could do it (illegally) by [terminating the cable with a junction box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=QbjcEo7fo0A)* *this is illegal*, and fit a furnace-style fuse (a fuse and switch or socket in the form-factor of a common receptacle).  You see this all the time around construction sites, usually made of a 4x4 steel junction box and a domed cover. I don't like it because those knockouts are actually pretty fragile, as will be the fuse and cover in your case.

Bottom line is that a "reel up extension cord" of this type is *a very concept* which is technically infeasible.

The only way to make that work would be to use 90C-rated #10 wire.  At that point you're coming off a 40A derate at 40% giving 16A.  Or, make the drum large enough that the wire only wraps around it 4 times - that would require a 2'4" drum in your case.

#10 wire is a fair bit more expensive and would more than double the cost of the reel.  But if I wanted that, that's exactly what I'd do. Get somebody else's cord reel that lets you use your own cord... and use #10 cordage.

[image]

---

* By the way, now watching this video, the builder made a very poor choice of cable clamp. They make proper strain-relief cable clamps made for cordage (that one is made for Romex). And you have to ground to the metal box, which then takes care of the outlet grounding. And the person recommends a "screw-and-clamp" spec-grade recep but doesn't explain that adequately. Amateurs!!!

Comment: were you saying I was trying to defeat the fuse? That was actually the opposite of my intention - I am trying to figure out how to add a fuse instead of just a normal outlet to the end of the cable.

Comment: @DavidDoria No, Harper wasn't accusing you of anything! He is explaining **why** there is a fuse in the first place, since an ordinary (not reel) 16 AWG extension cord does **not** have a fuse. And now I feel better that my comment hunch of "rolled up on an enclosed reel" was likely right on target.

Comment: The reason you see junction-box extension cords mostly on construction sites is that OSHA has a special exception allowing them to be used there: https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/standardinterpretations/1992-06-17

Comment: @DavidDoria My bad, I misread your question.  After I hit "post" I re-read your question, realized my mistake and immediately fixed it (like 5 minutes later).   I hadn't seen your comment until just now.

Comment: @NateS. I'm pretty sure they mean with a better box than a common 4x4.  I use those all the time and the knockouts get knocked out VERY easily.  It would make more sense with a cast aluminum box.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Hm, an interesting read, thanks. However I either missed the point or am still confused - since it's 16awg wire which apparently HAS been certified to be safe as long as it has a 10A fuse. So I guess I'm confused why I can't use (or even find) a NEMA 5-15R with a fuse that I could attach to the end?

Comment: You don't find a NEMA 5-15R with a fuse because the standard US design simply doesn't need it. Typical setups are either "make sure everything can handle 15A and let the circuit breaker in the panel take care of things" **or** "include a 15A circuit breaker in the device (commonly included in many surge protectors) (and again still 15A). AIUI (from reading posts here, no personal experience) many UK (other European too? not sure) devices include fuses all over the place. But US code is predicated on most residential stuff (extension cords, small appliances, etc.) being "good enough" with...

Comment: the standard 15A or 20A circuit breaker. End result though is that you can't make certain things both "top quality" and "inexpensive" - hence, inexpensive extension cord reels with throwaway 10A fuses **or** expensive extension cord reels. Can't have it both ways.

Comment: @DavidDoria Nobody makes them because the need is so very unusual.  Normally you're simply required to use large enough cable to carry 15A, and #16 *extension cords* are allowed that **if they're not coiled**.  If they are coiled, they should use larger wire.  So you have a corner case where the manufacturer is too cheap to use appropriate wire for the job, yet wanted to muscle it through UL listing anyway.  In other words that product is a waste of your time.

Comment: I mean you'll need [one of these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cooper-Bussmann-Plug-Fuse-Holder-with-Outlet-Box-Cover-Unit-SRU-BC/202303204) and a sturdy junction box to put it in, with a strain relief, you'll be $30 into this thing real quick and you'll have a crippled cord that can't run a lot of tools. Good money after bad...

Comment: Ok how about this then - I put a 10A breaker in the panel that feeds the outlet that the reel is plugged into, and just put a normal 3 prong outlet on the end of the reel?

Comment: No good, nothing keeps you from plugging that cord in elsewhere.  For that matter you could hardwire it into a 2-space subpanel with a 10A breaker, but you actually want more like a 6A breaker to be a good thermal match for those wires.  Breakers are very permissive and slow to trip.   Still the cost will be undue.

Comment: Gah. Ok so sounds like "buy a different one with a breaker built in instead of an unreplaceable fuse" is the sane approach.